# Multiple messages while logging

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

While logging if I want to give multiple messages how would I do it. For example:

```
logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s Money: %(message)s Chore: '
      datefmt='Date: %Y-%m-%d, Time: %H:%M:%S')
```

I have a message for money but who do I get a message for the Chore part. I tried this:

```
Chore = input("What chore did you do? ")
logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s Money: %(message)s Chore: ',Chore,
      datefmt='Date: %Y-%m-%d, Time: %H:%M:%S')
```

but I got this message:

```
  File "allowance.py", line 14, in <module>
  datefmt='Date: %Y-%m-%d, Time: %H:%M:%S')
  TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'datefmt'
```

BTW this is not the full code only a piece of it my formatter variable is already in a function. Just this code won't do anything.

Comment: Is the extra message fixed for all uses of your `Formatter`?

Comment: @DavisHerring I don't get what you mean.

Comment: Your failing example *constructs* the `Formatter` with the value of `Chore`.  Is that sufficient, or do you really want to pass a different chore each time you *use* the logger?

Comment: The parameters for `Formatter` are: `logging.Formatter(fmt=None, datefmt=None, style='%')`. In  your second example, you passed a string as `fmt`, then `Chore` as second parameter, so it will be assigned to `datefmt`, then again your format string as a keyword parameter for `datefmt`, so you passed 2 different values for the same `datefmt` parameter. `Chore` should probably not be passed here.